# Number of subspaces in a quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\{f(x)\mid f(x) \text{ is a polynomial of degree} \leq  5 \}$ and $W=\{ p(x)\mid p(x)=p(1-x) \}\subset V$ be a subspace of $V$. In Z3

Find number of subspaces $V/W$.

I knew the result that 
number of distinct subspaces of $\dim k$ are
$$\frac{(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots(q^n-q^n-1)}{(q^k-1)\cdots(q^k-q^k-1)}$$ 
Is it a right result to find number of subspaces?
If it's not then give a hint to solve the problem

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Latex to write your question. Also in what field are you working?

Comment: What is $q$? If your question is about vector spaces over some specific kind of field, you should say it.

Comment: Are you asking for subspaces of the quotient set $V/W$?